# Why does the dtype change to object when appending a row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Create a DataFrame, print info on it append a row, print info again. The dtype of all the columns changes to object. Why?

```
myData = np.array([134.29, 136.97, 250.31, 312.28])
mySeries = pd.Series(myData,index=['IBM','P&G','Microsoft','Home Depot'], name="Stock Price")
myData1 = np.array(['120.573B', '336.72B', '1.885T' , '335.974B'])
mySeries1 = pd.Series(myData1, index=['IBM','P&G','Microsoft','Home Depot'], name="Market Cap")
myData2 = np.array([120_573_000_000, 336_720_000_000, 1_885_000_000_000 , 335_974_000_000])
mySeries2 = pd.Series(myData2, index=['IBM','P&G','Microsoft','Home Depot'], name="Market Cap Raw")

myDataFrame = pd.concat([mySeries, mySeries1, mySeries2], axis=1)
#print(myDataFrame)
print(myDataFrame.info())

# After adding the row below, the dtype of numeric types change to object

myData = np.array([20.99, '100M', 100000000 ])
mySeries = pd.Series(myData, index = myDataFrame.columns, name = 'HML')
myDataFrame = myDataFrame.append(mySeries, ignore_index=False)
#print(myDataFrame)
print(myDataFrame.info())


<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 4 entries, IBM to Home Depot
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------          --------------  -----  
 0   Stock Price     4 non-null      float64
 1   Market Cap      4 non-null      object 
 2   Market Cap Raw  4 non-null      int64  
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 128.0+ bytes
None
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 5 entries, IBM to HML
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------          --------------  ----- 
 0   Stock Price     5 non-null      object
 1   Market Cap      5 non-null      object
 2   Market Cap Raw  5 non-null      object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 160.0+ bytes
None
```

Comment: I understand the problem now, based on the comments in the answer below. My big mistake is not asking the question properly because I need to learn how to fix it.

Comment: haha...well, consider accepting this answer and asking a new question then, because I've been under the impression the whole time that you're just curious why :)

Comment: That's a mostly fair assumption, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `Series` object containing objects of different incompatible types, the dtype of that `Series` becomes `object`.

When you create `myData` and `mySeries` the second time, that's exactly what's happening:

```
>>> myData = np.array([20.99, '100M', 100000000 ])
>>> mySeries = pd.Series(myData, index = myDataFrame.columns, name = 'HML')
>>> mySeries.dtype
dtype('O')
```

Right after that, you append that `Series` (of dtype `object`) to the dataframe. Since the `object` type is more general than the dtypes of the various columns of the dataframe, those columns get converted to the more general `object` dtype.

Comment: I didn't do that. I appended a Series identical to the original Series' used to create the DF. There are no incompatible types.

Comment: The second `myData` is `np.array([20.99, '100M', 100000000 ])`. There are different datatypes in that array. Then, you created a series from it (`mySeries`). So `mySeries` (the second one) is a dtype of `object`, right?

Comment: The second series uses the identical syntax as the first. How are they different?

Comment: The data that it's containing is different, @nicomp. `myData`, `myData1`, and `myData2` (in the first part of your example) are collectively of different dtypes, but each individual series has the same dtype within itself, i.e. `myData` only contains floats, `myData1` only contains strings, and `myData3` only contains ints.

Comment: But `myData` in the second part of your example contains different dtypes, some of which can't be automatically converted to any others. So, the lowest common denominator among them all is `object`, which is what they're converted to. Because a `Series` object can have only one dtype.

Comment: The difference between the first part and the second part of your example are how you're building the dataframe. In the 1st part of your example, you're buildin up the DF column-by-column, but in the second part, you're building it up row-by-row.

Comment: OK,. I get it now. How do I prevent this from happening? I guess I asked the question incorrectly, now I must start over.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to fix it:

```
tmpSeries = pd.to_numeric(myDataFrame['Stock Price'])
myDataFrame['Stock Price'] = tmpSeries
```

This changes the column to float64 from object. to_numeric can also be used to convert to other numeric types.